# Exceptions incorrectly handled by default catch block in 64-bit C++Builder application

Tags: delphi, exception, c++builder

My company has created a 64-bit NT Service application in C++Builder.  One of our customers is encountering a problem where the service starts to log multiple unhandled C++ exceptions.

After many months of diagnostic builds and trial and error, we've determined that Delphi/C++ exceptions are no longer caught in the correct catch block but rather in the default catch block.  When the service detects this scenario it runs a diagnostic in a new thread and logs the results.  The diagnostic throws various exceptions in a loop and catches those exceptions.

Here is a simplified example:

```cpp
// ESomeException descends from Exception

void TestThrowESomeException() {
  throw ESomeException("test");
}

void UnhandledCPPExceptionTest() {
  int eSomeExceptionCount = 0;
  int exceptionCount = 0;
  int unhandledCount = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 25; ++i) {
    try { TestThrowESomeException(); }
    catch (ESomeException&) { ++eSomeExceptionCount; }
    catch (Exception&) { ++exceptionCount; }
    catch (...) { ++unhandledCount; }
  }

  String msg = "Test results:\r\n";
  if (exceptionCount > 0 || unhandledCount > 0) {
    msg += String::Format(
      "eSomeExceptionCount = %d\r\n"
      "exceptionCount = %d\r\n"
      "unhandledCount = %d\r\n",
      ARRAYOFCONST((eSomeExceptionCount, exceptionCount, unhandledCount))
    );
  }
  else
    msg += "all tests succeeded";

  Logger::Add(msg);
}
```

When the server is not in the erroneous condition the log message will be:

```
Test results:
all tests succeeded
```

When the server is in the erroneous condition the log message will be something like:

```
Test results:
eSomeExceptionCount = 17
exceptionCount = 0
unhandledCount = 8
```

Analyzing these results shows that the `ESomeException` catch block was executed 17 times and the default block was executed 8 times.

We have not been able to reproduce this issue in any of our environments.  The customer's server is an AWS EC2 instance with Windows Server 2012 R2.  We do not know the AWS instance type, Windows update history, or the AMI used to create their server (if they used one).  We have asked for more details and I will update this question once known.  We replicated their instance in AWS using the information we know and were unable to reproduce the behavior.

Our project was built using RAD Studio 10.4 Update 2.  It is configured to use runtime packages.

At this point, we are at a loss as to what steps to take to troubleshoot further.  Has anyone encountered a similar problem with C++Builder 64-bit exception handling?  Are there any steps we can take to gather more information to determine the cause?  Could there be a setting in our project configuration that would help diagnose or fix this issue?

### Edit 5/23

I have modified the diagnostic code to inspect the SEH exception information in attempt to determine why the `catch` isn't catching.  Here is an example of the new test throw:

```cpp
int exc_filter(EXCEPTION_POINTERS*) {
  return EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER;
}
```

```cpp
  EXCEPTION_POINTERS* xp;
  try {
    __try {
      try { TestThrowESomeException(); }
      catch (ESomeException const&) { ++eSomeExceptionCount; }
      catch (Exception const&) { ++exceptionCount; }
    }
    __except (exc_filter(xp = GetExceptionInformation())) {
      ++sehCount;
      diagStr = AnalyzeException(xp);
    }
  }
  catch (...) { ++unhandledCount; }
```

`AnalyzeException` analyzes the exception pointer and returns some details to hopefully figure out what is wrong with the exception object/structure:

```cpp
bool IsDelphiExceptionCode(DWORD Code) {
  return Code == 0xEEDFACE || Code == 0xEEDFADE || Code == 0xEEFFACE || Code == 0xEEFFADE;
}

String AnalyzeException(EXCEPTION_POINTERS* Xp) {
  if (Xp == nullptr)
    return "XP is null";
  if (Xp->ExceptionRecord == nullptr)
    return "XP.ExceptionRecord is null";
  PEXCEPTION_RECORD xr = Xp->ExceptionRecord;

  String result;
  String codeStr = ExceptionCodeToString(xr->ExceptionCode);
  String hexStr = "0x" + IntToHex(static_cast <unsigned int> (xr->ExceptionCode));
  if (!codeStr.IsEmpty())
    codeStr += " (" +  hexStr + ")";
  else
    codeStr = hexStr;
  result +=
    "Code: " + codeStr +
    ", Flags: 0x" + IntToHex(static_cast <int> (xr->ExceptionFlags), 4) +
    ", Count: " + String(xr->NumberParameters) +
    ", [";
  for (int i = 0; i < EXCEPTION_MAXIMUM_PARAMETERS; ++i) {
    if (i > 0)
      result += ",";
    result += IntToHex(static_cast <int> (xr->ExceptionInformation[i]), 1);
  }
  result += "]";

  if (IsDelphiExceptionCode(xr->ExceptionCode)) {
    result += ", ";
    try {
      try {
        Exception* exception = reinterpret_cast <Exception*> (xr->ExceptionInformation[1]);
        if (exception == nullptr)
          result += "Exception is null";
        else {
          result += "Class: " + exception->ClassName() + ", ";
          result += "Message: " + exception->Message;
        }
      }
      catch (Exception const& e) {
        result += "Exception while inspecting: " + e.Message;
      }
    }
    catch (...) {
      result += "Exception while inspecting";
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

It is my intention to gather as much detail as possible before opening a case with Embarcadero.  It is possible that this problem is fixed in RAD Studio 11.1 but we have not finished evaluating that compiler for our production builds.

Comment: Exceptions should always be caught by `const` reference. Try replacing the `catch(...)` with an SEH `__try/__except` (`try/catch` uses SEH internally on WIndows), [`GetExceptionCode()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/getexceptioncode) will get you the ID of the thrown exception. VCL exceptions will always be `0xEEFFACE` or `0xEEFFADE`, and if you want more diagnostics, dig into the exception's RTTI to see why it doesn't match your `catch`'s.

Comment: I will rewrite the tests to have three levels of exception handling.
`try {
  __try {
    try {
    catch (ESomeException const&) {}
    catch (Exception const&) {}
  } __except (EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER) {}
} catch (...) {}
`

Comment: As for the RTTI suggestion, are you suggesting I grab RTTI inside of the SEH exception handler or the catch?  If the suggestion is for inside of the catch then that won't provide me much help because the exception is already being caught correctly.  If the suggestion is for inside of the __except then can you provide an example of how to get the RTTI of the exception?  I have scoured documents looking for some way to do this but haven't found anything.

Comment: If `__except` catches an RTL-style exception that *should* have been catch by `catch(ExceptionClass)` instead, then check `GetExceptionCode()`, and if the code is `0xEEFFACE` or `0xEEFFADE` then `GetExceptionInformation()->ExceptionRecord.ExceptionInformation[1]` is a pointer to the `Exception` object, from which you can then query its `ClassName()`, `Message`, etc.

Comment: It might be unrelated but Years back (in 32bit code and in C++ builder series) I encounter a similar bug that some of `AnsiString`  inbuild methods had caused an exception and `catch/try` ignores them completely all the time  IIRC it was `AnsiString::ToDouble()` along with differnet than OS specified decimal separator (like `"0,5"` instead of `"0.5"` due to different language settings in OS) had to use `atof` and or own conversions instead

Comment: I have modified our diagnostic to log more details about the exceptions.  I did want to note that the ExceptionCode I get in my testing for RTL exceptions is `0xEEDFADE`.